# Why It displayed the name, address, and birthday display as null when I'm using real Identification card?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ocr, tesseract, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to extract information such as name, bday, address in an image file (ID). I tried to use the notepad to create a sample ID picture, I write the name, address, bday. like this then make this as an image:

Last Name: Dela Cruz
First Name: James
Date of Birth: 2000-11-05
Address: Brgy. Leno, Makati City

When I'm using this the API is working it can extract the text, but when I used a real Identification card, It cannot extact the name,address ,bday it show null value. Eventhough the labels from the ID and the label on the code are the same.

[image: Sample Expected Output ()]

[image: Null Output]

Here's my code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ImageDataController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExtractText(IFormFile imageFile)
    {
        if (imageFile == null || imageFile.Length == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest("No image file was provided.");
        }

        var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await imageFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            var ocr = new IronTesseract();
            var result = ocr.Read(tempFilePath);
            var extractedText = result.Text;

            // Extract name, address, and birthday using regular expressions
            var lname = ExtractLastName(extractedText);
            var fname = ExtractFirstName(extractedText);
            var dateofbirth = ExtractBirthday(extractedText);
            var address = ExtractAddress(extractedText);
            

            return Ok(new { lname, fname, dateofbirth, address });
        }
        finally
        {
            // Delete the temporary file
            System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilePath);
        }
    }

    private string ExtractLastName(string text)
    {
        
        var lnamePattern = @"Last Name:\s*(.+)";
        var match = Regex.Match(text, lnamePattern);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return match.Groups[1].Value;
        }

        return null; // Return null if name is not found
    }
    private string ExtractFirstName(string text)
    {
        
        var fnamePattern = @"First Name:\s*(.+)";
        var match = Regex.Match(text, fnamePattern);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return match.Groups[1].Value;
        }

        return null; // Return null if name is not found
    }

    private string ExtractBirthday(string text)
    {
        var birthdayPattern = @"Date of Birth:\s*(\d{1,4}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,4})";

        var match = Regex.Match(text, birthdayPattern);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var dateString = match.Groups[1].Value;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out DateTime date))
            {
                return date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
        }

        return null; 
    }

    private string ExtractAddress(string text)
    {
        
        var addressPattern = @"Address:\s*(.+)";
        var match = Regex.Match(text, addressPattern);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return match.Groups[1].Value;
        }

        return null; 
    }


}
```

Comment: did you debug and see what args you get from the request?

Comment: Image optimize filter: https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/examples/ocr-image-filters-for-net-tesseract/

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain No, I didn't

Comment: @Ihdina oww, gonna try this.

Comment: @JoeRick Is the background color of the real id card the same as the background color of the id card simulation? If it's different, then you have to make the background color on the real card the same as the background color in the simulation by filtering the image, so the output will be the same.

Comment: From the information you provided, It's hard to find the reason, Maybe you can refer to this [Docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-ocr/net-core)